# Add row from another TableView - Swift

Tags: swift, string, tableview, segue, protocols

I'm trying make it so that when I click on one item of my array on listtableviewcontroller it will pass this selection to dataaddedtableviewcontroller and append the selection so that I can keep on adding to the list. [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Won6.png)

I have tried to pass the data using protocols and delegates, however all that is passed is the whole list itself (I think this is mainly because I used a button instead of clicking on the cell, as I didn't know how to do otherwise). I have also tried to pass the data using segues, however I cannot seem to append the data once I click on the cell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

FirstViewController:

```
protocol ListTableViewControllerDelegate {
    func addNew(todo: String)
}

class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var delegate: ListTableViewControllerDelegate?

    var list = ["chicken", "phone", "water"]

    @IBAction func saveToList(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.addNew(todo: "\(list)")
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return list.count
    }

}
```

SecondViewController:

```
class DataAddedTableViewController: UITableViewController, ListTableViewControllerDelegate {

    var dataAdded = [String]()

    func addNew(todo: String) {
        dataAdded.append(todo)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return dataAdded.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataAdded[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? ListTableViewController {
            destVC.delegate = self as ListTableViewControllerDelegate

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your code as well?

Comment: do you have 2 arrays with some data, which you shows into tableViews?

Comment: @M_G added, thank you for replying!

Comment: @SergeyHleb yes, I’ve added the code if that helps?

Comment: where is your method, which check selected row? or you presses some button and insert in second VC String all of Strings array?

Comment: @SergeyHleb I want to pass the data when the cell is selected if that what’s you mean? Not from a button. How would you do this? Many thanks!

Comment: yes. you need to use TableView's delegate methods

Comment: do you understand how to use it?

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible for you to write the code for that as I’m slightly confused at the moment?

Comment: few minutes I need

Comment: oh, M_G edited his answer. check it. is it helps to you?

Comment: @SergeyHleb it’s working perfectly now! Thank you once again for your help!! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out the index of the list item the user tapped on. Currently you are just passing the whole list. This line needs to be adjusted:

Before:

```
@IBAction func saveToList(_ sender: Any) {
   delegate?.addNew(todo: list)
   navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

After:

```
@IBAction func saveToList(_ sender: Any) {
    let index = CODE_NEEDE_HERE //figure out how to find out the index of the list
    delegate?.addNew(todo: list[index])
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

I guess you had a valid reason not to use the delegate method [tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview)?

Using `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` the solution could be something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = list[indexPath.row]
    delegate?.addNew(todo: item)
}
```

Comment: I don’t have a valid reason, Im relatively new to coding and  am basically trying to learn how to do this piece of code. If you can offer any suggestion to as to how I can do it through didselectrowat I would be so thankful! Also what code is needed for ‘index’? Many thanks!

Comment: Ok, you should definitely stick to the given delegate methods by UITableViewDelegate and take a look on some basic tutorials or WWDC sessions related to this topic. In general the mentioned delegate method passes a parameter which contains the section of the tableview (only useful when using a sectioned tableview) and the zero-based index (row) of the list.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it was greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome, added a simple example using tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)

Comment: Thank you so much it’s worked!! I really appreciate all your help! 